# How to create map with key and a list of values in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dictionary

In Java we can create

```
private map<String, List<String>> map = HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>();
```

How to create a map with keys and lists of values in JavaScript?

I want to put key as country name and list of values are country states. How to do in JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
map = {"country1": ["state1", "state2"], "country2": ["state1", "state2"]}
```

OR dynamically

```
var map = {};
map["country1"] = ["state1", "state2"];
map["country2"] = ["state1", "state2"];
```

Comment: how to create dynamic map?

Comment: Sharing a post that explains in a better way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33020554/how-to-create-a-map-in-javascript-with-array-of-values-dynamically

Answer (score 1):

Here a java and javascript coder.

```js
//Variable map, contains a instance of Map with a constructor of String and Array of String.
let map = new Map([[String.prototype, [String.prototype]]]);

//Put values in map.
map.set('Country1', ['State1', 'State2']);
map.set('Country2', ['State1', 'State2', 'State3']);
map.set('CountryN', ['State1', 'State2', 'State3', 'StateN']);

//Iterate map and print the content of this.
map.forEach((value, key) => {
  console.log(`Country: ${key} States:[${value}]`);
});
```