# Node JS Map Object Memory Leak?

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-leaks

I have a map/dictionary object in Node JS where the key is a string and the value is an array of objects. So a (key, value) looks like ("123", [obj1, obj2, obj3]) and so on.

I have the following code to add new objects (a "vehicle") to the map, but it is giving me "process out of memory" error:

```
        ...
        var vehiclePositionsDict = new Map();
        ...
        if (vehiclePositionsDict.has(vehicle.vehicle_id)) {
           // If key already exists, add the "vehicle" object to array.
           (vehiclePositionsDict.get(vehicle.vehicle_id)).push(vehicle);
        } else {
           // The key does not yet exist so create a new value.
            var vehicles = [];
            vehicles.push(vehicle);
            vehiclePositionsDict.set(vehicle.vehicle_id, vehicles);
        }
```

I am not sure why I get the out-of-memory error. If I simply replace the above code with the one below, then there is no out-of-memory error:

```
            vehiclePositionsDict[vehicle.vehicle_id] = vehiclePositionsDict[vehicle.vehicle_id] || [];
            vehiclePositionsDict[vehicle.vehicle_id].push(vehicle);
```

What's the difference?

I am running Node JS v5.0.0 on a Windows 7 64-bit environment. The map/dictionary gets cleared every 15 seconds or so.

Comment: Isn't your second block of code just setting a property on the object just like you would set a property on any plain object whereas the first block of code is actually using the `Map` object features.  You could accomplish what you want to do with either as long as your keys are strings or simple string conversions, though a `Map` is more purpose-built for that (it supports non-string keys).  I would guess the out of memory is caused by something in the context this is in and not only caused by these specific lines of code.

Comment: For starters, you're using Map wrong: you should use the get() and set() methods rather than the bracket syntax; otherwise, you're modifying properties of the object instead of entries in the Map. Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon That's what I thought, so in my original code it is using get() and set(). I got the second block of code from here http://stackoverflow.com/a/33020716

Comment: I found the issue. The code above (the first block) is fine. The memory-leak comes from somewhere else inside a loop.